How to make Bazel remote caching $USER agnostic?
I'm working on a Bazel/Bazelisk configured project and need to use remote caching (using bazel-remote) in order to let developer machines use build artifacts generated on powerful build machines.
This scenario already works for me in general, but when I started to use Bazelisk the build cache was not used on all machines anymore.
Analyzing the execution log you get via --execution_log_json_file=<PATH> I found out that Bazel implicitly (and silently) captures the current user's $PATH in environmentVariables but also </path/to/home>/.cache/bazelisk/downloads/bazelbuild/bazel-7.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin:</path/to/home>/.cache/bazelisk/downloads/sha256/<SHA>/bin gets added to $PATH.
While it makes sense to take $PATH into account when looking for cached artifacts, and Bazelisk's bin folders have to be considered.. this breaks remote cache capabilities of course when user names differ (at least by default).
How am I supposed to solve this?
Should I create a 'well known folder' on every build machine/container which is user-agnostic and point Bazelisk to that folder?
Or can I somehow tell Bazel/Bazelisk to keep the .cache folder where it wants it to be (or where I want it to be) but not take it as input for environmentVariables used for the remote cache key? How?
And there might be some more options that come to my mind to workaround this behavior, but what's the intended approach?

Typically, one forces the action path be consistent with --incompatible_strict_action_env.
(It's not just the bazelisk PATH entry to worry about. Developers like to mess with PATH to, for example, add their custom script directories.)

This feels like a workaround for some hastily knocked together default behavior (I don't want to find --incompatible* anywhere in production code), but judging from your Bazel talks it looks like you'd know if there was a more 'bazelesque' approach..

May you have tried to set BAZELISK_HOME to a path that suits your needs, like the repo root? Be aware also the downloads during the setup of bazel will be placed there.
This can be achieved by using a .bazeliskrc file in the root of your repo
BAZELISK_HOME=./.repo_local_cache/bazelisk


Problem is - in contrast to what ./<relative/path> suggests, the provided folder won't be expanded once but every time bazel is being executed. So the provided BAZELISK_HOME has to be absolute in order to be valid in other directories than the project root. Anyway you don't have to set XDG_CACHE_HOME to tell Bazelisk where to store and look up its bazel executables.
